# gitlab Request to merge branch-A into develop (3 commits behind) should I worry?

Tags: git, merge, gitlab

When creating a merge request in gitlab I often get a message:
Request to merge branch-A into develop ([x] commits behind) 
what does gitlab want to tell me?
should I worry or do I need to fix something (what)?

Answer (score 12):

After some time a **merge request** is open in a project it is normal that the version of the branch you are trying to merge into becomes outdated due to other people merging their own changes to it.

Gitlab helps you by showing how much the version of the branch you updated is behind the remote branch.

Being behind will not set any hindrance to the act of merging, but it is a common practice to `rebase` your commits on top of the branch your merging into. This will make your merge request updated by putting your commits chronologically after the ones that already are in that branch. That approach makes the work of the person responsible for the merge easier because the commiter himself has already resolved any conflicts that would have happened.

To do a `rebase` following the scenario you proposed would be like this:

```
# Add a remote named `upstream` pointing to the original repository
git remote add upstream https://gitlab.example.com/example/your_project.git

# Fetch the latest commmits from `upstream`
git fetch upstream

# Checkout our branch-A
git checkout branch-A

# Rebase our branch on top of the `upstream/develop` branch
git rebase upstream/develop

# If needed fix any conflicts that may have appeared and then `git rebase --continue`  

# Push the changes to the branch of your merge request
git push --force origin branch-A
```

***Note:*** The `--force` flag is necessary when you push because you are rewriting the commit history of origin/branch-A. From [git's doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---force):

> [--force] can cause the remote repository to lose commits; **use it with care.**

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. But what do I need the `git remote add upstream` for? Wouldn't it also be possible to only do a `git rebase develop` when all remote branches are fetched already?

Comment: you can just merge instead of rebase. Or else you know what you do, I wouldn't recommend rebasing

Comment: Recommending use of 'git push -- force' is bad practice.  --force should only be used by an admin user who knows what they're doing as the effect can be devastating and unrecoverable.

Comment: @JasonCrocker in the example we're using `--force` against our own branch so there is no issue in doing so. `git push --force` is a tool and should be used when appropriate.

Answer (score 10):

If you're seeing a 'behind by X commits' message, gitlab is indicating that the branch you're merging into has moved on from the point where you branched.

When you review the diffs in gitlab, they can seem confusing, possibly suggesting that you're about to undo changes that are implemented in later commits on the target branch.

If you want to be sure you're seeing exactly the changes that the merge will perform, the safest thing to do is to update the branch you want to merge by first merging in the target branch...

```
# fetch the latest code on all branches
git fetch

# checkout your working branch (if you're not already on it)
git checkout branch-A

# merge in the target branch
git merge origin/develop
```

Fix any conflicts that may arise, then commit them:

```
# stage changes & commit
git add .
git commit

# push changes to origin
git push
```

If you now refresh the merge request page on gitlab, the 'behind' message will disappear and the diffs will reflect the changes you've made only.

This is much safer than rebasing your branch as it does not require a `--force` push.  It also means that the chronology of the git timeline matches what actually happened, so if you're trying to track down an issue in the future, you won't be mislead by a re-writing of history.

The downside is that the commit history can look a bit more messy.

Comment: Yes, but if the merge requires approvals, would this method invalidate the approvals and force us to get the code reviewed again?

Comment: Since the purpose of approvals is to ensure that commits are reviewed by a third party, I would certainly expect any changes you have to make to fix the merge to require approval again (I've not used gitlab for a while so I can't confirm this).  If you have merge requests hanging around so long that they routinely get out of date, there's something amiss somewhere else in the process I would think.

Answer (score 5):

In addition of @alejdg's answer,
to prevent this

> [--force] can cause the remote repository to lose commits; use it with care.

You could also use `--force-with-lease` which is safer than `--force`,
if others commits are inserted between your `rebase` and your `push --force` [more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52823692/git-push-force-with-lease-vs-force)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers above, I usually do the below to rebase my local branch and push. Usually I will have remote origin added to the local git repo, if I am a contributor.

```
git pull
git checkout <your-branch>
git rebase origin/<remote-branch>
git push --force origin <your-branch>
```

Comment: perhaps worth saying that the first command `git pull` happens when you are checked out  in the main branch (`git checkout main`, then `git pull`, then `git checkout <your-branch>`...)

Answer (score 0):

This is a beginner's understanding of what is going on. You will find answers on git with a higher level of "git wording". But this is how I found my steps through the git jungle. ;) Hope it helps some other beginner.

Start with checking out your main (here develop) branch:

```
git checkout develop
git pull --all
```

Then switch to your new branch-A (that has been worked on in parallel to other commits which are already merged into "develop").

You might either pick each commit separately to be more cautious (recommended) or rebase right on top all of the previous commits of that last MR.

Also, in general, look up `stash` and `stash apply`, then you do not need any commits, it is much easier.

```
git checkout branch-A
git stash #(if you do not use commit, stash is recommended)
git rebase -i develop
```

`-i` means interactive, meaning that you will need to change things in an editor popping up.

*(If you do not use `-i`, you do not get the editor, which should also be fine since then, the same settings will be used automatically, but that is in this case only, in other cases, you might really need it, thus it seems good to get used to that editor).*

This "todo-editor" opens with the commits that led to the last MR for "develop" (which is like the main in your case).

Leave the `pick` in front of all of the commits in that "todo-editor", this is the default anyway, and change only the last one to `edit` instead of `pick` since your new commit shall be edited by all of the commits you do in the following, not the other commits. Your new commit shall be on top of the MR of the "develop" branch, and all other picked commits should be those before the last MR with "develop".

It looks like:

[image]

Then write-close that editor and you will now see all of the conflicts of the first "pick" when you look up

```
git diff
```

or better you go into codium/vscode and accept just the current or the incoming code at each conflict (files and folders with conflicts are marked red, and in the file, use the arrow up / down to find the conflicts).

Then:

```
git rebase --abort
```

Do not `git commit` or `git push` during `rebase`, instead, use `--abort` and start rebase again, or use `git rebase --continue` if you are sure about what you are doing and do not need to check the intermediate results. `push` can harm your commit tree, `commit --amend` will change the earlier commits, and `commit` will create new commits from the old ones.

`Rebase` is not for this. When you use `rebase`, you want to come back to the starting point at the end and only *then* you can `git commit --amend` and `git push -f` if needed.

Anyway. Going on with the work:

Repeat the steps above for each commit, the next would be the second pick. The third commit is already the "edit" commit. If you reach that, repeat again the steps above, and when there are no conflicts anymore:

```
git add .
git stash apply #(or if you use commit: git commit --amend)
git push -f
```

And you have set your new branch on top of the work that was in your latest "develop" MR.

*In my case, the rebase on the "develop" also led me to the MR commit of the previous "develop" MR itself. I ended up in adding a duplicated commit of that MR, which was wrong. This happens if you - wrongly - `commit --amend` on an existing MR commit that is already merged. Thus, I had one commit more before my latest commit, so that I had two commits instead of one on top of the "develop".

Therefore, better do not use commit, but `stash` / `stash apply` on each picked commit.*