# git push --force-with-lease vs. --force

Tags: git, git-push

I am trying to understand the difference between

```
git push --force
```

and

```
git push --force-with-lease
```

My guess is that the latter only pushes to the remote *if the remote has commits that the local branch doesn't have*?

Comment: the "local *remote tracking branch*".  Basically meaning the remote has to look like what your client expects it to look like.  `git help push` has use-cases explaining its purpose (basically to keep you from trashing a change someone just pushed up).  What's a little unclear to me is how the remote tracking branch works.  But presumably typically it's going to need to look exactly how it looked last time you did a `fetch` or `pull` with no new commits.

Comment: @zzxyz: the actual implementation of `--force-with-lease` is similar to that of compare-and-swap instructions on modern CPUs: the one who wants the swap to occur supplies the expected value and the new value. The system doing the swap compares the expected value with the true current value, and does the swap if and only if the two are equal. With `git push`, the expected value is whatever is in the remote-tracking name, e.g., `git push --force-with-lease origin X` sends your own `origin/X` along with the new desired value; `origin`'s Git tells you if it did the exchange, or not.

Comment: If the Git at `origin` did the exchange, you are done. If not, you can run `git fetch origin` to pick up the *new* current value, rework your changes if needed, and run another force-with-lease compare-and-swap to try again.

Comment: from v2.30 Release Notes: "git push --force-with-lease[=<ref>]" can easily be misused to lose commits unless the user takes good care of their own "git fetch". A new option "--force-if-includes" attempts to ensure that what is being force-pushed was created after examining the commit at the tip of the remote ref that is about to be force-replaced.

Comment: I would name `force-with-lease` or at least think of it as --> safe-with-lease

Answer (score 820):

`force` overwrites a remote branch with your local branch.

`--force-with-lease` is a safer option that will not overwrite any work on the remote branch if more commits were added to the remote branch (by another team-member or coworker or what have you). It ensures you do not overwrite someone elses work by force pushing.

I think your general idea surrounding the command is correct. If the remote branch has the same value as the remote branch on your local machine- you will overwrite remote. If it doesn't have the same value- it indicates a change that someone else made to the remote branch while you were working on your code and thus will not overwrite any code. Obviously if there are additional commits in remote then the values won't be the same.

I just think of `--force-with-lease` as the option to use when I want to make sure I don't overwrite any teammates code. A lot of teams at my company use `--force-with-lease` as the default option for a fail-safe. Its unnecessary in most circumstances but will save you lots of headache if you happen to overwrite something that another person contributed to remote.

I'm sure you looked at the docs but there might be some more wordy explanation contained in here:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

Comment: This answer makes no sense because you can't "overwrite code" in Git. Perhaps you meant it doesn't make other people's commits unreachable? But it doesn't even do that.

Comment: This comment does not make sense, but for another reason: it's not obvious from this answer how this differs from just `git push`. It appears that `git push` does exactly the same thing described here.  And from what I've picked up, `--force-with-lease` has a disadvantage in a form of possibility to overwrite remote if you did fetch, but did not do merge of a remote/pull. 

What's the `--force-with-lease` is for then?

Comment: i just rewrote remote branch by my version that was behind using `--force-with-lease` :(

Comment: @VitaliiLebediev the difference is that with normal push (i.e., no force) the push won't get through at all if for example the remote is ahead of your local branch. You can still force push (with and without lease) in that case. Similarly when the push cannot be fast-forwarded on the remote. Regarding force-with-lease after you already fetched: If you fetched, you are expected to look into the commit graph (or use other means) to make sure you really want the remote branch to point to that force pushed commit and drop any commits that your local repo knows about.

Comment: @sKopheK probably too late for your situation, but the advantage of --force-with-lease is that even if you dropped commits (intentionally or accidentally) from the remote branch, they are already in your local repository and you can reset the branch again via reflog. That means even *if* something goes wrong, it can be rolled back much more easily and force-pushed again within seconds, likely before anyone is affected (if you realize and fix it immediately).

Answer (score 123):

> Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources.

The "compare and swap" mentioned by [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52823692/git-push-force-with-lease-vs-force#comment92565722_52823692) and in [his other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37688141/6309) is further illustrated by the [sources of Git itself](https://github.com/git/git/).

> the latter only pushes to the remote if the remote does not have commits that the local branch doesn't have?

That feature was introduced in [this commit](https://github.com/git/git/commit/28f5d176110d2ed768a0a49159993c7a02d8cb15) (Dec. 2013, Git v1.8.5-rc0)

> `--force-with-lease` will protect all remote refs that are going to be updated by requiring their current value to be the same as some reasonable default, unless otherwise specified;
>
> For now, "some reasonable default" is tentatively defined as "**the value of the remote-tracking branch we have for the ref of the remote being updated**", and it is an error if we do not have such a remote-tracking branch.

So "lease" means:

> "`force-with-lease`": You assume you took the lease on the ref when you fetched to decide what the rebased history should be, and you can push back only if the lease has not been broken.

"You assume you took the lease on the ref": So "lease" is used to describe a safety mechanism for force pushing changes to a remote repository.

When you fetch from a remote repository, you essentially get the latest state of the repository at that time. Think of this as taking a "snapshot" or a temporary "lease" on the repository's state.
The "lease" implies that you are aware of the repository's state as of the last fetch and are operating under the assumption that this state has not changed since.

When you use `git push --force-with-lease`, you are telling Git: "I want to force push my changes, but only if the remote repository is in the same state as my last fetch."
In other words, you can push your changes as long as no one else has pushed any updates to the remote repository since your last fetch.
If someone else has introduced changes to the remote repository (thereby "breaking the lease"), the push will be rejected. That helps prevent accidental overwriting of others' work.

The sources still mention "cas":

> - This option was originally called "**`cas`**" (for "compare and swap"), the name which nobody liked because it was too technical.
> - The second attempt called it "lockref" (because it is conceptually like pushing after taking a lock) but the word "lock" was hated because it implied that it may reject push by others, which is not the way this option works.
> - This round calls it "force-with-lease".
>   You assume you took the lease on the ref when you fetched to decide what the rebased history should be, and you can push back only if the
>   lease has not been broken.

So: "`git push --force-with-lease` vs. `--force`"

As I mentioned in "[`push --force-with-lease` by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43726130/6309)", as Git 2.13 (Q2 2017) mentions, that the option `--force-with-lease` can be <del>*ignored*</del> if a background process (like the ones you find in an IDE with a Git plugin) runs `git fetch origin`.
In that case, `--force` prevails.

As [Pavlus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1571480/pavlus) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52823692/git-push-force-with-lease-vs-force/52937476?noredirect=1#comment111636964_52937476):

> it is not ignored per se, it is just now you have identical refs for local remote head and remote head, so `--force-with-lease` will behave correctly -- compare these two, and if in that interval of time between fetch and push, someone updated remote, it won't behave as `--force`, it will still fail.

---

Another difference: before Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), pushing a ref whose name contains non-ASCII character with the "`--force-with-lease`" option did not work over smart HTTP protocol.
It would work with `git push --force`.

See [commit cd85b44](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cd85b447bfc09ddfab660048883de6a07d893097) (21 Jul 2020) by [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c2796ac](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c2796ac1c2807a46d1db90e47c892ba96bfdb276), 30 Jul 2020)</sup>

> ### [`remote-curl`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cd85b447bfc09ddfab660048883de6a07d893097): make `--force-with-lease` work with non-ASCII ref names
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Frej Bjon</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: brian m. carlson</sup>

> When we invoke a remote transport helper and pass an option with an argument, we quote the argument as a C-style string if necessary.
> This is the case for the cas option, which implements the `--force-with-lease` command-line flag, when we're passing a non-ASCII refname.
>
> However, the remote `curl` helper isn't designed to parse such an argument, meaning that if we try to use `--force-with-lease` with an HTTP push and a non-ASCII refname, we get an error like this:
>
> ```
> error: cannot parse expected object name '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"'
> ```
>
> Note the double quote, which `get_oid` has reminded us is not valid in an hex object ID.
>
> Even if we had been able to parse it, we would send the wrong data to the server: we'd send an escaped ref, which would not behave as the user wanted and might accidentally result in updating or deleting a ref we hadn't intended.
>
> Since we need to expect a quoted C-style string here, just check if the first argument is a double quote, and if so, unquote it.
> Note that if the refname contains a double quote, then we will have double-quoted it already, so there is no ambiguity.
>
> We test for this case only in the smart protocol, since the DAV-based protocol is not capable of handling this capability.
> We use UTF-8 because this is nicer in our tests and friendlier to Windows, but the code should work for all non-ASCII refs.
>
> While we're at it, since the name of the option is now well established and isn't going to change, let's inline it instead of using the #define constant.

---

Git 2.30 (Q1 2021) adds [`git push --force-if-includes`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64627761/6309)

> When a local branch that is based on a remote ref, has been rewound and is to be force pushed on the remote, "`--force-if-includes`" runs a check that ensures any updates to the remote-tracking ref that may have happened (by push from another repository) in-between the time of the last update to the local branch (via "`git pull`", for instance) and right before the time of push, have been integrated locally before allowing a forced update.

Comment: Correction about last paragraph: it is not ignored per se, it is just now you have identical refs for local remote head and remote head, so `--force-with-lease` will behave correctly -- compare these two, and if in that interval of time between fetch and push, someone updated remote, it won't behave as `--force`, it will still fail.

Comment: @Pavlus Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: What's a "lease" in the case of git? I take it it's not an apartment rental. I'm asking because I'm trying to understand _"you took the lease on the ref when you fetched"_

Comment: @Clockwork I have edited the answer to define lease. Think of it like renting a car (fetching the repository). You have it for a set period (until your next fetch), and you assume it is in the same condition as when you rented it. If you return the car (push your changes) and it is in a different condition than expected (someone else has made changes), there is a conflict that needs resolution.

Comment: Funny: 10 years later, Git 2.44 finally removes any "CAS" (Compare And Swap) reference from the code. See [commit a762af3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a762af3dfd9450bf1d6153faa620cb42efb7daa8)

Answer (score 64):

`git push --force` is destructive because it unconditionally overwrites the remote repository with whatever one have locally.  git's `push --force` is strongly discouraged as it can destroy other commits already pushed to a shared repository. One of the most common causes of force pushes is when we're forced to rebase a branch.

For example. We have a project with a feature branch that both Alice and Bob are going to work on. They both clone this repository and start work.
Alice initially completes her part of the feature, and pushes this up to the main repository. This is all well and good. Bob also finishes his work, but before pushing it up he notices some changes had been merged into master. Wanting to keep a clean tree, he performs a rebase against the master branch. Of-course, when he goes to push this rebased branch it will be rejected. However not realising that Alice has already pushed her work, he performs a push --force. Unfortunately, this will erase all record of Alice's changes in the central repository.

What `--force-with-lease` does is refuse to update a branch unless it is the state that we expect; i.e. nobody has updated the branch upstream. In practice this works by checking that the upstream ref is what we expect, because refs are hashes, and implicitly encode the chain of parents into their value.

Here is a good post regarding `git push --force` and `git push --force-with-lease`: [–force considered harmful; understanding git’s –force-with-lease](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/04/force-with-lease/)

Comment: what I don't understand - if you rebase with master, then you should be able to push *without* `--force-with-lease`?  Why is `--force-with-lease` necessary after rebasing with master?

Comment: @AlexanderMills there may have some possibility that cause problem. If you are the last person that push this to master then no problem but there is another person who working with another task then it may cause serious problem. Say at first A - B - C was in master , At first Alice make it A - B - C - D - E and same time Bob make it A - B - C - F - G. If Alice is the the last person push in master after rebasing A - B - C - D - E - F - G will not cause any problem but another person Tom try to push A - B - C - D - E - R at same time in master disaster will happen !!!

Comment: `--force` does not lose commits, it just detaches them. They can be resurrected by their hashes, as in `git checkout <SHA>` or `git reset --hard <SHA>`, assuming the maintainter of the remote repo does not do any GC or pruning operations.

Comment: "git's push --force is strongly discouraged as it can destroy other commits already pushed to a shared repository" this statement is strongly opinion-based. Doing a force push is part of a normal git rebase code review workflow. Also like mentioned already you can retrieve the commits even after doing this.

Comment: Both this answer and the linked article make it sound like it's normal for a push to be rejected after rebasing a feature branch onto the main branch. That's just not true. After a successful rebase to main, a normal push should succeed.

Answer (score 43):

Assuming any pre-receive hooks on the server accept the push, this will always succeed:

```
git push --force
```

Whereas this runs a specific client-side check before proceeding:

```
git push --force-with-lease
```

You can run the specific check yourself manually.  Here's the "lease-checking" algorithm:

1. Figure out your current branch.
2. Run `git for-each-ref refs/remotes`. Take note of the commit-id your git client thinks corresponds to the upstream state of your current branch.

E.g., if you are on branch "foo", take note of the commit-id associated with "refs/remotes/origin/foo".

3. Determine the actual commit-id of the remote branch on the upstream git server right now.
4. Only let the "git push" proceed if the commit-ids you extracted from step 2 and step 3 agree.  In other words, only proceed if your local git clone's notion of upstream agrees with actual upstream.

There's a sad implication here:  since `git fetch` updates all refs under "refs/remotes/origin/*" to their latest versions, this combination of commands is essentially identical to `git push --force`:

```
git fetch

# The command below behaves identically to "git push --force"
# if a "git fetch" just happened!

git push --force-with-lease
```

To work around this inherent weakness in `git push --force-with-lease` I try to never run `git fetch`.  Instead I always run `git pull --rebase` whenever I need to sync with upstream, since `git pull` only updates a single ref under refs/remotes, keeping the "lease" of `--force-with-lease` useful.

Comment: if the check is client-side, is there potential for a race condition? i.e. somebody else pushes changes after the check but before the forced push?

Comment: I think this answer is significantly easier to understand and more useful than the higher rated ones. Thank you for explaining this so well!

Comment: Good explanation, but I disagree with the conclusion. IMHO you should *never* use either `--force` or `--force-with-lease` if there is *any* chance that another person would push to the same branch (unless you personally warned all other contributors). If you rebased a feature branch onto a "shared" branch, then a normal `git push` should succeed (no need for any `--force`). If not, someone else pushed before you, and you need to rebase and `push` again. If you push to a "private" branch (i.e. no one else pushes to it), then it does not make a difference which `--force` you use.

Answer (score 4):

`Force-with-lease` is not necessarily safe. It just works as Sylvie said.

**One note:** In git a branch is just a pointer on a commit. And commits point to zero or more parent commits. Even if you changed the branch entirely with a hard git reset and a forced push or a push with - - force-with-lease without wanting it, that's not necessarily a big problem.

You can use your local `git reflog` to see how your local tip on the branches (Where was HEAD at that time?) has changed and reset and push the branch again. Then you only lose new commits on the remote branch, but even they might be restored by the team members.

Comment: Just a reminder for most people do not know. git list (and all its alias variants) can take the  --reflog parameter which then lists also all commits that are normally invisible. Much more useful than the git reflog command alone.