# Git: How to squash all commits on `master` branch?

Tags: git

I'm looking for a way to squash **all** git commits into a single big commit in `master` branch. I fully understand the consequences of what I'm trying to do, no need to explain that this is dangerous or that it's not the right way to go - I want to lose all my history and turn this repository into a single big commit.

The main problem is: I have no other living branches, no local commits, and all of the previous commits have **already been pushed** to remote `master`.

Hacky scripts are also welcome.

Comment: First thing that comes to my mind: `git rebase -i <first-commit-hash>`. Then use your editor's query replace functionality to replace all the `pick` by `squash`and save. Then `git push --force`.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I would use `git reset --soft`:

```
git reset --soft id-of-first-revision-of-master
git commit --amend -m "single commit for master"
```

Then you can `git push --force` wherever you need that new branch.

#### Update

I can think of another simple way to do it, with more git commands:

```
git checkout --orphan some-branch
git commit -m "First commit"
git branch -f master # move the local branch
git checkout master
git branch -d some-branch # delete the temp branch
```

It could also be done like this, in a more hackish fashion:

```
git commit-tree -m "First commit" HEAD^{tree}
```

That will write a revision.... if you check it out, you will have a single revision, content will be exactly like it is where you were standing before.... feel free to move the local branch (as explained in the previous recipe)

Comment: @eftshift0 the git command `git checkout --orphan -b some-branch` is causing an error `fatal: 'some-branch' is not a commit and a branch '-b' cannot be created from it`. Did you actualy mean `git checkout --orphan some-branch`?

Comment: might make sense without the -b. I mean, if you are checking out an `--orphan`, then it's a _new_ branch, right? Then no need to specify -b. Perhaps that's the logic.

Comment: I did first five commands here, and then 'git push --force-with-lease' - which did the trick.  Only 1 commit on my remote, and my commits with sensitive data were gone.

Comment: 5 years to push? Going over a slow dial-up?

Answer (score 15):

You can still modify the history on the upstream by using `git push --force-with-lease`. However you have to be aware of the consequences.

Using `git push --force` will create a parallel tree on your upstream so all the developers may find themselves lost in a legacy branch.

In order to squash your history, simply do:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~10
```

Where `10` is the number + 1 of commits you want to squash together. If you want to squash **all** the commits, then just refer your `<first-commit-hash>` instead of `HEAD~10`. Then on the editor you select `squash` for all the commits you want to group together. You can do search/replace: `pick` by `squash`

Once done, simply push your changes:

```
git push --force-with-lease
```

I would never recommend to do `--force` because if another developer has pushed a commit in the meantime you will erase its move. By using `--force-with-lease` Git will prevent you to push if somebody else has pushed on the top of your last change (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52823692/git-push-force-with-lease-vs-force) for more details).

Comment: I believe instead of using the `<first-commit-hash>`, you can use `git rebase -i --root` to rebase all the way to the initial commit

Comment: The `--root` parametr does the trick for me. The solution whit `HEAD~number` or first commit hash does not work for me - they finish with two commits - not the only one.

Comment: Perfect @RuChernChong Thank you, using `--root` also did the trick for me