# Git Rebase -> Why is there a merge when pulling?

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

I created a branch to develop a new feature. Since this new feature was develop entirely as a new project, the only possible source of conflict would be in the solution file.

As the feature was developed, the master branch was updated several times. When I completed my development and testing, I did:

```
git checkout master
git fetch
git pull
git checkout myFeature
git rebase master
```

The rebase (and all other commands) went fine and no conflicts/errors/problems were reported. My next step was to `git status` and the result was:

> On branch myFeature
>   Your branch and 'origin/myFeature' have diverged,
>   and have 7 and 5 different commits each, respectively. (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

When I `git pull` a merge was open and looking at the history, my commits were duplicated. This duplication, in my point of view was not supposed to happen. I was expecting that my commits were supposed to be re-applied AFTER the last (currently) commit on the master.

Am I doing something wrong or my expectation is wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Why is there a merge commit

When you do a rebase, you're changing Git history. When you do a pull again, Git tries to combine both histories again. As by default `git pull` is a `git fetch` + `git merge`, this will lead to a merge commit.

This isn't what you want after changing history as it will (partly) reverts you history changes. Unfortunately the hint of `git status` is a bit misleading...

#### What should you do after a rebase / changing history

After changing history (e.g. rebase), you need a force push so you will get that history also on the remote. You're telling git then "the history is different, but trust me, that's intended".

It's recommend to use a  "force push with lease": `git push --force-with-lease` - see [git push --force-with-lease vs. --force](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52823692/git-push-force-with-lease-vs-force).

#### Steps to fix the current state

Luckily you could go back before the `git pull` by using the Git reflog!

This will fix the wrong pull and there won't be any conflicts to solve :)

So steps to do:

1. Find correct commit in the reflog `git reflog`, so before the `git pull` (note: you could quit the reflog by typing <kbd>q</kbd>)
2. Git reset to that commit, e.g. `git reset 327fb961e --hard`
3. Double check and do a `git push --force-with-lease`.

Note: if you are making a mistake with `git reset`, you could use the `git reflog` again :)

Note 2: the reflog is only on your local machine

Comment: so after `git rebase master` I do a `git push --force-with-lease` instead of `git pull`?

Comment: Yes indeed! You get it :)

Comment: I've seen a ton of answers explaining how to _avoid_ getting into this situation, but this is the first one I've seen that clearly explained how to recover if you've _already_ gotten into this situation -- huge life saver, thank you @Julian!!

Comment: FYI, this answer assumes that you've performed the rebase on your local branch first. However, for folks like me who've performed the rebase on the _remote_ branch first (eg. via GitHub), this is the sequence of steps I needed to follow to avoid this situation:
Do NOT pull changes from rebased remote branch to local branch -- that's what causes the merge+duplicate commits! Instead, simply force-delete the local branch, then re-checkout the rebased remote branch to create a new local branch. At this point, both your remote and local branches are rebased and in sync with each other.

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer looks great.  Just trying to illustrate visually what's going, in case that's helpful:

Since `git rebase` modifies history, you branch after rebasing looks different from the one you have on origin.

**origin/master**:

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E
```

**yourbranch, origin/yourbranch:**

```
A -> B -> F -> G -> H
```

After rebasing, **yourbranch** would look like:

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F -> G -> H
```

Then, when you pull **origin/yourbranch**, you would have:

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F -> G -> H - I (merge commit)
      \                              /
        -> F -> G -> H -------------
```

Since the histories are different, it becomes a normal, non-fast-forward merge.  Effectively, your remote and local branches have become different branches.

Answer (score 1):

This part was enough for rebasing with `master` branch.

```sh
git checkout master
git fetch
git pull
git checkout myFeature
git rebase master
```

---

However, you can just use the following command instead of all the above command to do the same thing.

```sh
$ git pull origin master --rebase
```

After this all the commit hash will be rewritten that's why `git status` showed that your branch has diverged.

Ignoring this, you could run the following command to push the rebased code to the remote branch.

```sh
$ git push origin HEAD -f
```

---

While rebasing if you face conflicts and you are not willing to continue the rebase, you can just run `git rebase --abort` to abort the rebasing.

In any case, if you find yourself in the middle of some unwanted commit related hazard, you can follow the following steps.

- `git reflog` - to find the last perfect commit & note its commit hash
- `git reset --hard <commit-hash>` - provide the last perfect commit hash

It will take you to the last perfect code of the repo.