# How to push repo after reverting local branch?

Tags: git

so I have a git repo that I had made commits and pushed the repo to the server. Then I rolled back a few commits with git revert to a previous commit on local. Now when I try to push to the server I get the error

> hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is
>   behind hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes
>   (e.g. hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again. hint: See the 'Note
>   about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

I understand that I reverted on my local branch, so now the remote branch has commits that aren't on the local branch. I just want to also remove those commits on the server. I just want to be able to push my local branch the way it is and "replace" the head on the server. How do I do that? I don't want to pull the changes from the server since I want to trash those anyways.

Comment: Use the [`--force`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---force), Luke.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+hint%3A+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+tip+of+your+current+branch+is+behind

Answer (score 1):

This is the time you need to execute a `--force-with-lease` push:

```
git push --force-with-lease <remote> <branch>
```

For example:

```
git push --force-with-lease origin 1234-my-feature
```

Warning: `--force` and its variant "with lease" allow you to change the history of a branch, effectively deleting one or multiple commits. Therefore relying on force-pushes in distributed environments should remain the exception, or only be performed if you are sure nobody is relying on `1234-my-feature` when creating their own branches. See [git push --force-with-lease vs. --force](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52823955/2375855) for an explanation of their difference.

One common convention is: feature-branches may be force-pushed to by their respective owners/authors, but once they are merged to a `master` or shared `development` branch, their history may no longer be modified. But your mileage may vary, depending on how loose/strict your development environment is organised.