# How to change the commit history in GitHub?

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-rebase, git-reset

I have tried `git rebase` in interactive mode to squash commits. I have also tried `git reset` in soft mode, then made a single commit.

It seems to have changed my `git log`. But when I need to push to GitHub, It says could not push, I need to pull first due to divergent branches.

After pulling and then pushing, when I go to GitHub, I find that the **number of commits has only increased**.

How can I change the history on the commits page of a GitHub repo?

Comment: For a public branch which is already being shared by others besides yourself, please consider just using `git revert` instead of an interactive rebase, the latter which rewrites history.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim, for this suggestion. It is certainly useful in some of my cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point

> It says could not push, I need to pull first due to divergent branches.

you should do

```
git push -f
```

This will get you the desired result. Hopefully other contributors, if any, on whatever you are working on, don't mind if the commit history has changes.

Suggested reading: [Git Push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use `git push --force-with-lease`.
[git push --force-with-lease vs. --force](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52823692/git-push-force-with-lease-vs-force)