# Change entire git branch history to match another branch's history

Tags: git

Say I have 2 branches, `develop` and `p3` (production 3).

Regardless of any commit history on `p3`, I want to make **p3's entire commit history now exactly match develop's commit history**.

`p3` tries to stay on track with `develop`, but people constantly merge test branches into `p3` and resync it improperly with `develop`.

How do I make the entire commit history of `p3` match `develop` so I can then call the following?

```
git push --force-with-lease origin p3
```

Comment: Could you explain in more details what's missing from eftshift0's answer ? FWIW, it looks complete and detailed enough for me.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to basically get rid of p3's history

```
git branch temp p3 # backup current p3
git checkout p3
git reset --hard develop
git push --force origin p3 # replace branch in remote too
```

Answer (score 4):

> How do I make the entire commit history of p3 match develop

Locally, you mean? First `git fetch` so that your remote tracking branches are up to date, and `git pull` both for `p3` and for `develop`, so that your actual local branches are up to date. Then

```
git branch -f p3 develop
```

Presto, you rip the name `p3` right out of the commit that it currently points to and attach it to the commit that `develop` points to. They are now absolutely identical branches. The history of `p3` *is* now the history of `develop`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to re-create p3 based on the current develop HEAD, you would:

- make sure to have the latest develop HEAD from the remote origin
- force p3 to be re-created at origin/develop HEAD commit

That would be using the more recent command [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) ([less confusing than the old obsolete `git checkout` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309))

```
git switch -C p3 develop
```

As mentioned in the [`git switch` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch#Documentation/git-switch.txt--Cltnew-branchgt):

> Similar to `--create` except that if `<new-branch>` already exists, it will be reset to `<start-point>`.
> This is a convenient shortcut for:
>
> ```sh
> $ git branch -f <new-branch>
> $ git switch <new-branch>
> ```

From there, you can force push p3. Without lease (see "[`git push --force-with-lease` vs. `--force`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52937476/6309)").